# Target the next element relative to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically, and in a very schematic way, I need to target the first element who has a specific attribute relative to the element who got the event.

```
<div data-path="2" class="section">
  ... Nope.
</div>

<div data-path="1" class="section">
  <a data-path="2" class="trigger" href="#">Foo</a>
</div>

<div data-path="1" class="section--2">
  ... Nope.
</div>

<div data-path="2" class="section--3">
 I need to target this one, but not the sections previous to the trigger.
</div>

<div data-path="2" class="section--4">
  ... Nope.
</div>
```

I can't figure how to achieve this. It seems to be pretty simple but I'm just stuck on this since two days. I try to play with .next() and .nextUntil() but it doesn't work properly.

Any help are welcome and sorry for my english.

Edit : To be clear, what I need is when a click on the .trigger, I need to target the first next section who has the same data-path attribute, but not the sections before the trigger.

Comment: Which element will raise the event, and what attribute are you looking for?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "doesn't work properly."?

Comment: You haven't explained what you need, nor what you've tried, clearly.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. I need to target the data-path attribute. I need to match the attribute of the .trigger and the section.

Comment: @user2486937 you can edit your question to include those details.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for "document.getElementById("id")". http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: What do you want from the code and what have you tried for two days? Can you please create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Could you also provide the jQuery that you are trying to use so we can get a better idea of what you are attempting?

Comment: @user2486937: Are you by any chance looking for this functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mUt9H/ ? If yes, then `nextAll` is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `nextAll` to get to the next element which has the same property value and then use the first one out of that:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mUt9H/1/***

*Relevant Code*:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    var dp = $(this).data("path");
    var txt = $(this).parent().nextAll("div[data-path='" + dp + "']").first().text();
    alert(txt);
});
```

Your trigger is an anchor, so first you need to get to its parent div and then traverse to the next elements. Hence, `$(this).parent()...`.

**Edit**: (regarding your comment)

Just chain a `.first()` to the statement and you are good to go.

`.nextAll("div[data-path='" + dp + "']").first()...`

Comment: It work, but I don't want to select all of the sections who are after the trigger. Only the first next to the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('a.trigger').click(function () {
    var target = $(this).parent().nextAll('div[data-path="'+$(this).data('path')+'"]').first();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ykyqF/)**